# Title is not visible for UIContextualAction (UITableView swipe to delete - iOS 11)

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios11, uitableviewrowaction

I am using `UIContextualAction` to implement swipe to delete functionality for `UITableViewCell`. I use `+ (instancetype)contextualActionWithStyle:(UIContextualActionStyle)style title:(nullable NSString *)title handler:(UIContextualActionHandler)handler` method to construct `UIContextualAction` and later set an image to it using `setImage:` property.

However when I run this code and try to swipe delete, only image is shown in the menu. The title is missing. When I comment out the `setImage` property, title is displayed. Why is this so? Am I missing something in the implementation or is this a bug with Apple?

Answer (score 15):

`UIContextualAction` supports *either* text *or* image. By setting the image with `setImage:`, you basically remove the title you set when creating the object. If you want text *and* image, you'll have to create images with embedded text.

**EDIT**

My answer was based on my own experience, unfortunately the official docs for that particular class are of no help at all. I also found a hint on the issue [here](https://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/uitableview-swipe-actions-in-ios-11/) (*"By specifying an image, the title in the initializer is not displayed"*).

In your comment you say that if the height is >91px, both title and image are shown. That matches this [radar](http://www.openradar.me/33396671) (there it says that the height should be >=91px), so it might be a bug after all.

Looks like for the moment, the only options are to either create images with embedded text, or increase the cell height to 91px.

**EDIT 2**
As pointed out by laka's comment, using an image with embedded text has accessibility drawback, e.g. VoiceOver will not be able to identify the semantics of the action. You can use `accessibilityCustomActions` to overcome this problem (see
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47529860/how-to-add-accessibility-label-for-voiceover-at-swipe-action-configuration-for-r)).

Comment: But I have observed that if the height of UITableViewCell is more than 91 points, both title and image is shown.

Comment: Yes, Embedded text seems to be the best solution for now. I am doing it now in my code. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: but it is shown with the title centered, and the image above it... awful output (iOS 11.3)

Comment: From an accessibility standpoint, embedded text is really bad.

Answer (score 1):

As a solution we could render text into image using `UIGraphicsImageRenderer`

```swift
let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds)
contextAction.image = renderer.image { context in
    // draw your image and text using Core Graphics API here
}
```

It is workaround, but Apple doesn't provide us another way to do it ...